# Rundeck Project SCM exportUuidBehavior "original" overwrites my job UUID

Tags: version-control, uuid, rundeck

I’m having trouble with configuring SCM UUID import and export behavior in Rundeck. I want to use the import behavior ‘archive’ and the export behavior ‘original’. And what I expect after reading the Rundeck documentation is that these behaviors should not modify the UUIDs of my jobs in my git repository. However, when I export a job, the UUID is overwritten in my git repository.

I found the following documentation on the ‘archive’ behavior: “Git SCM Plugins: ability to import jobs from a repo and "archive" the original UUID. Allows sharing a repo among multiple "non-production" projects within the same Rundeck server, and still maintain static UUIDs for the production project.”
https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/history/2_x/version-2.6.10.html

This exactly describes what I want, so I guess it must be possible, however it’s not working for me.

I'm using Rundeck version 3.3.10.

This is the config of my import plugin:

```
{
   "url":git@github.com:***/***.git,
   "fetchAutomatically":"true",
   "pullAutomatically":"true",
   "dir":"/home/niek/rundeck/projects/UUID_test_2/scm",
   "filePattern":".*\\.yaml",
   "importUuidBehavior":"archive",
   "useFilePattern":"true",
   "strictHostKeyChecking":"no",
   "sshPrivateKeyPath":"keys/priv_key",
   "format":"yaml",
   "branch":"master",
   "gitPasswordPath":"",
   "pathTemplate":"${job.group}${job.name}.${config.format}"
}
```

This is the config of my export plugin:

```
{
   "url":git@github.com:***/***.git,
   "fetchAutomatically":"true",
   "pullAutomatically":"false",
   "_createBranch":"",
   "dir":"/home/niek/rundeck/projects/UUID_test_2/scm",
   "committerEmail":"${user.email}",
   "baseBranch":"master",
   "committerName":"${user.fullName}",
   "strictHostKeyChecking":"no",
   "sshPrivateKeyPath":"keys/priv_key",
   "branch":"master",
   "format":"yaml",
   "exportUuidBehavior":"original",
   "gitPasswordPath":"",
   "pathTemplate":"${job.group}${job.name}.${config.format}"
}
```

I would appreciate it if someone could help me with this.

EDIT:

To clarify what my end goal is, take the following job definition that is in my git repository:

```
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: test-uuid-job
  loglevel: INFO
  name: test_uuid
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: uname -a
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: test-uuid-job
```

This job must be available in different projects, where each project has a different branch of the same repository as source. The UUID of the job in the production branch should never change and should stay 'test-uuid-job'. However, when I import and then export the job in a project from a development branch using the 'archive' and 'original' behaviors, the UUID that is exported to git is still the newly assigned UUID of the imported job in the development project. While I expected it to stay 'test-uuid-job'. Otherwise, when the development branch is merged into the production branch, the UUID will change there too.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself.

Take a Rundeck project that has Import UUID Behavior set to 'archive' and Export UUID behavior set to 'original'. After importing a job that does not yet exist in the project, you first need to do the following steps to make the right behavior kick in:

- At the Jobs page use the 'actions' button of the new job to import the job a second time
- Edit the Job, and save it without making any changes.

Now the job has no export actions anymore. If you do edit and make changes to the job now, a new export action will be available that won't change the UUID that is set in the Git repository.

Yes, these two steps seem like they shouldn't do anything, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project Settings > Setup SCM and disable the SCM Export, then click on "Configure", set the "Export UUID Behavior" to "preserve", scroll down and click on the "Setup" button (the config is saved and SCM is enabled again).

Any change keeps the UUID for your exported jobs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply MegaDrive68k. But setting the Export UUID Behavior to "preserve" doesn't fix my problem. The UUID that is set in my git repository is still overwritten by the newly created UUID from my rundeck development project. (I made an edit in my post to clarify what I'm trying to achieve.)